# Keeping a video call app running when switching apps in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-permissions

I am developing a video call app, and all of my camera, networking, encoding, decoding and audio are running in my activity.

The main problem is that whenever the user locks their screen or switches apps, the activity is shut down and I lose the call.

I've tried wakelocks, notifications, foreground services, nothing keeps my activity alive past Android 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "and all of my camera, networking, encoding, decoding and audio are running in my activity" -- very little of that code belongs in an activity. Much of the camera bits are unavoidable for being in the activity, particularly for showing the camera preview. Everything else should be outside of the activity. "the activity is shut down" -- you might want to explain, in programming terms, what you mean by this. Do you mean that your activity moves to the background? Do you mean that your activity is destroyed? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: THis scenario screams foreground service to hold everything, not an Activity.  The Activity should just be the UI to end call, mute, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for the activity to disappear when the memory is insufficient. You need to use the `foreground service` to keep the program. Just like the music player, they all use the foreground service.